# Firefox CSS3 transition not working when toggled from external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I know there are bunch of questions already about CSS3 transitions not working in firefox. I think this one might be quite unique. As the transitions DO work when added into the relevant click functions within `$(document).ready()`  .  But once I've put the same code out into a basic js class and instantiated within `$(document).ready` it refuses to work in firefox 24. Works in all other major browsers.

Can anyone shed some light.

I've put up a test site here: http://test.gladekettle.com.au/modal/

```
var ModalApp = function  (options) {
    //default options
    var defaultOptions = {
        modalElem       : "#modalresponsive",
        z               : 99,
        overflowvisible : true,
        scrollbardelay  : 1000
    }

    for (i=0; i < options.length;i++){
        if(typeof options[i] === "undefined"){ options[i] = defaultOptions[i];
        }
    } //for - set default options if not defined.

    var $modalObj = $(options.modalElem);
    var zindex   = options.z;

    $modalObj.css('z-index', zindex);
    $modalObj.addClass('modalhidden');

    this.close = function() {
        $modalObj.removeClass('scrollvisible');
        $modalObj.removeClass('modalvisible').addClass('modalhidden');
        $('.modalactive').removeClass('modalactive');
    };
    this.open = function() {
        $('html').addClass('modalactive');
        $modalObj.removeClass('modalhidden').addClass('modalvisible');

        setTimeout(function() {
            $modalObj.addClass('scrollvisible');
        }, options.scrollbardelay);

    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with "external js files". The culprit is `.modalactive { overflow: hidden; }`, which gets set/unset to `html` on click and seems to be canceling out the transitions for whatever reason.
You may verify this by disabling the rule, either live on your site with the developer tools or see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3Aa8/).

You should [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi) and stop using that rule.